# I want to make this age_alarm function return nothing when I put str

Tags: python

```
def age_alarm(age):
  print(f"you are {age} years old")
  if age < 18:
    print("you cannot buy alcohol")
  elif age==18:
    print('Congratulation. Now you can have it')
  elif type(age) is not int:
    return None
  else:
    print('enjoy your drink')
age_alarm(18)
age_alarm('d')
```

I want to return nothing when I use age_alarm('sth') but it keeps return you are d years old
what should I do?

Comment: Put your third condition at top of your function.

Comment: The comparison `age < 18` will throw an error on Python 3 if `age` is a string. Do you still work with Python 2? But in that case the f-string shouldn't work. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `print()` is always called inside `age_alarm`.

If you don't want the function to print anything in case a string is passed in, you need to add a check and return *before* the print anything.

For example:

```python
def age_alarm(age):
  if type(age) is not int:
    return None

  print(f"you are {age} years old")

  if age < 18:
    print("you cannot buy alcohol")
  elif age==18:
    print('Congratulation. Now you can have it')
  else:
    print('enjoy your drink')

age_alarm(18)
age_alarm('d')
```

prints

```
you are 18 years old
Congratulation. Now you can have it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def age_alarm(age):
    if not isinstance(age,int): #checks if age isn't an integer.
        print(f"{age} is not an actual age")
        return # if age isn't an int it will return None
    
    print(f"Your age is: {age}")

    if age < 18:
        print("You cannot buy alcohol.")
    elif age == 18:
        print("Now you can buy alcohol.")
    else:
        print("Enjoy your drink.")
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def age_alarm(age):
    print(f"you are {age} years old")

    if type(age) is not int:
        return None
    else:
        if age < 18:
            print("you cannot buy alcohol")
        elif age==18:
            print('Congratulation. Now you can have it')

age_alarm(18)
age_alarm('d')
```